# Element stop dragging when cursor leaves div area react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, draggable

i've been trying to implement a draggable div in react, basically i would use the mouse to click and drag the element around or even the finger if i'm on mobile.
Problem is that when i move the mouse too fast and cursor leaves div's area the element stops been dragged. It's like i'm not updating div's position fast enough to stay in pace with cursor speed.
Any idea how can i fix this?

Also i've been using top and left position to update the div's position, is there any advantages in using css translatex/y instead?
What would it differs?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pos: {
        x:0,
        y:0,
      },
      rel: {
        x:0,
        y:0
      },
      dragging : false
    };
    this.draggable = React.createRef()
  }

  onTouchStart = e => {
    const touch = e.touches[0]
    const posTop = this.draggable.current.offsetTop
    const posLeft = this.draggable.current.offsetLeft

    this.setState({
      dragging: true,
      rel: {
        x: touch.clientX - posLeft,
        y: touch.clientY - posLeft
      }
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
  }

  onTouchMove = e => {
    if (!this.state.dragging) return
    const touch = e.touches[0]
    this.setState({
      pos: {
        x: touch.clientX - this.state.rel.x,
        y: touch.clientY - this.state.rel.y
      }

    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onTouchEnd = e => {
    this.setState({dragging: false})

  }

  onMouseDown =  (e) => {
    // only left mouse button
    if (e.button !== 0) return
    const posTop = this.draggable.current.offsetTop
    const posLeft = this.draggable.current.offsetLeft
    console.log(e.pageX,': pagex   ', e.pageY, ' : and pagey')
    console.log(posTop, ': posTop', posLeft, ' : posY')
    console.log('resultLeft :', e.pageX - posLeft, 'resultTop  :',  e.pageY - posTop)
    this.setState({
      dragging: true,
      rel: {
        x: e.pageX - posLeft,
        y: e.pageY - posTop
      }     
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onMouseUp =  (e)  => {
    this.setState({dragging: false})
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!this.state.dragging) return
    this.setState({
      pos: {
        x: e.pageX - this.state.rel.x,
        y: e.pageY - this.state.rel.y    
      }        
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{position:'relative', backgroundColor:'green', height:'100%', width:'100%'}}>
          <div style={{position:'absolute',backgroundColor:'red',
          height: '100px', width:'100px',
           left: this.state.pos.x + 'px', top: this.state.pos.y + 'px'}}
           onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart}
           onTouchMove={this.onMouseMove}
           onTouchEnd={this.onTouchEnd}
            onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
            onTouchMove={this.onTouchMove}
            onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}
            onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
            ref={this.draggable}
          > draggable div 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can put the code on stackblitz and it would work so you could try.
Any advice is more than welcome!

Stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-draggable-test-oezlsk

Comment: please add your code to stackblitz fork and post link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rort1p

Comment: link posted on the main topic

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
found out the problem.
I was assigning event onMouseUp onMouseMove to the div instead of at the father.
Furthermore the father didn't have proper height and width due to the root div which hadn't any dimension.

The updated and working code is the following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pos: {
        x:0,
        y:0,
      },
      rel: {
        x:0,
        y:0
      },
      dragging : false
    };
    this.draggable = React.createRef()
  }

  onTouchStart = e => {
    const touch = e.touches[0]
    const posTop = this.draggable.current.offsetTop
    const posLeft = this.draggable.current.offsetLeft

    this.setState({
      dragging: true,
      rel: {
        x: touch.clientX - posLeft,
        y: touch.clientY - posLeft
      }
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
  }

  onTouchMove = e => {
    if (!this.state.dragging) return
    const touch = e.touches[0]
    this.setState({
      pos: {
        x: touch.clientX - this.state.rel.x,
        y: touch.clientY - this.state.rel.y
      }

    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onTouchEnd = e => {
    this.setState({dragging: false})

  }

  onMouseDown =  (e) => {
    // only left mouse button
    if (e.button !== 0) return
    const posTop = this.draggable.current.offsetTop
    const posLeft = this.draggable.current.offsetLeft
    console.log(e.pageX,': pagex   ', e.pageY, ' : and pagey')
    console.log(posTop, ': posTop', posLeft, ' : posY')
    console.log('resultLeft :', e.pageX - posLeft, 'resultTop  :',  e.pageY - posTop)
    this.setState({
      dragging: true,
      rel: {
        x: e.pageX - posLeft,
        y: e.pageY - posTop
      }     
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onMouseUp =  (e)  => {
    this.setState({dragging: false})
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!this.state.dragging) return
    this.setState({
      pos: {
        x: e.pageX - this.state.rel.x,
        y: e.pageY - this.state.rel.y    
      }        
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp} onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove} style={{position:'relative', backgroundColor:'green', height:'120%', width:'120%'}}>
          <div style={{position:'absolute',backgroundColor:'red',
          height: '100px', width:'100px',
           left: this.state.pos.x + 'px', top: this.state.pos.y + 'px'}}
           onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart}
           onTouchMove={this.onMouseMove}
           onTouchEnd={this.onTouchEnd}
            onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
            onTouchMove={this.onTouchMove}          

            ref={this.draggable}
          > draggable div 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: The "parent" ;)